# django-dash: callback generated div id tag not found by other callback

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I have been working with plotly dash and especially django-dash for a while, and I am now facing an issue that I am not able to resolve. I am confusedbecause I have successfully used the same structure in the past. Hopefully a pair of fresh eyes could help me see what I am messing up.

Here is what I have:
=> first callback acquires data from a django session and that is used to create a dropdown menu that contains some dataframe extracted values:

```
@app.expanded_callback(
    Output('output_two', 'children'),
    [Input('dummy', 'value')]

)

def clean_data(file_path,**kwargs):
    file_path = file_path
    path = kwargs['request']
    path = path.session.get('path')
    print("path", path)

    ifc_file = ifcopenshell.open(path)

    work_plans = ifc_file.by_type("IfcWorKPlan")
    work_plans_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [schedule.id() for schedule in work_plans],
        'StartTime': [schedule.StartTime for schedule in work_plans],

        'FinishTime': [schedule.FinishTime for schedule in work_plans],

    })
    work_plans_df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(work_plans_df['StartTime']).dt.date
    work_plans_df['Status'] = "En cours"


    work_plan_id = work_plans_df['id'].unique()
    

    return html.Div(children=[html.Div(
        className='five columns',
        children=[
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="dropdown",
                options=list({'label': Id, 'value': Id} for Id in
                             work_plan_id
                             ),
                value='',
            ),
        ],
    ),
    ],
    )
```

Now, the second call should be using the submited dropdown value and use it to output something (I won't put the details of the calculations)

```
@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),

    Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks')
    ,State('dropdown','value')
)


def process_workplans(path, n_clicks,value,*args,**kwargs):
   if value is not None:
...#do calcs
      return dt.DataTable(...)
```

and finally here is the layout that I am using:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id="dummy"),
    html.Div(id="bed_file_path", children=[], style={'display': 'none'}),
    dcc.Store(id='output_one'),
    # wrapper dashboard
    html.Div([  # main-area
        html.Div([  # row that includes everything on the same "plane"
            html.Div([
                html.H4("Carnet d'entretien de mon bien"), html.Hr()]),
            html.Div([  # col sm-3, the entire length of the menu
                html.Div([  # control the frame in the whitch the menu is displayed
                    html.Br(),
                    html.Div([
                        html.Div([  # this make sure the content takes the 12 spaces within the 3 sm column
                            html.Div(

                                className='twelve columns',
                                children=html.P(
                                    "Sélectionner un chantier",
                                ),

                            ),

                            html.Div(id="output_two"),

                        ], className='col-sm-12',
                            style={"border-left": "white solid 0.4rem", "border-right": "white solid 0.4rem"}),
                        html.Br(),
                        html.Br(),
                        html.A(html.Button('Afficher les chantiers', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0,
                                           style={'border-radius': '4px', 'border': '1px solid #ff5402',
                                                  'background-color': 'white'}),
                               style={'margin-right': '3px', 'margin-bottom': '20px', 'margin-left': '30px'}),
                        html.A(html.Button('Refresh', style={'border-radius': '4px', 'border': '1px solid #ff5402',
                                                             'background-color': 'white', 'margin-bottom': '20px'}),
                               href='/eoq_modeling'),
                        html.Br(),

                    ], className='col-sm-12',
                        style={"border-left": "white solid 0.4rem", "border-right": "white solid 0.4rem"}),
                    html.Br(),
                ], className='row-for-params')

            ], className="col-sm-3"),
            html.Div([
                html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
     
            ], className="col-sm-9")
        ], className='row')
    ], className="main-area"),
], className="wrapper-dashboard")
```

The error that I am getting tells that `dropdown` cannot be found.
I can see that when the page is initialized, `dropdown` is not there but it gets there and the second callback is not able to update

I believe that a delay in the triggering of callback 2 could be an option but I can't find how to do that in django-dash documentation and dash `app.config[‘suppress_callback_exceptions’] = True` does not work with django-dash. Anyone got an idea on how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that:

1. You could create a dummy div & dropdown (i.e. the same structure that `clean_data()` will output) in your initial `app.layout`, then just overwrite it with new controls with your callback. i.e. that way you always have a control with the correct ID in the layout in order to avoid initialising on an incomplete layout.
2. Potentially [suppressing the initial call](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#prevent-callback-execution-upon-initial-component-render) to the second callback could avoid the issue?